# How can the loop integral of the magnetic vector potential, for a loop enclosing a toroidal inductor but outside of it, equal the nonzero flux inside?

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm stuck on an apparent contradiction and I can't find any explanation of it. --In a perfect toroidal inductor with current through the windings, there is a magnetic field and thus flux within the toroid but no magnetic field outside of it. The magnetic field equals the curl of the magnetic vector potential A, and therefore everywhere outside the toroid the curl of A equals zero. But as a result, any closed line integral of A equals zero. How then can the line integral of a loop which encloses the toroid through the donut hole (like the A-lines in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmy76.png)) equal the flux inside the toroid? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please ask this on PSE. As far as math is concerned : has it perhaps anything to do with the Torus having genus 1 ? Just thinking it is late at night here .

Comment: I just put this on PSE--thanks very much for the suggestion.